# Is there a way to configure Unity so that addressable textures don't compress at all?

Tags: unity-game-engine, compression, textures, jpeg, image-compression

Is it me or am I the only one who wants my JPG's untouched for my 2D puzzle game?  I would just like them to stay the way they are.  I use Photoshop to get them just right - the right size, the right color profile, everything right.

Is there a method to slip Unity the skip-me for post-process of the images before compile?  And just take them straight?

Comment: Your textures/sprites have compression in their import options. And your project is going to have quality settings too. Just configure things are you need them.

Comment: Yes but the question is *how* to configure to stop doing any compression work on the images?  I would like my images to run straight through without compression work.

Comment: You should change that title ... "hack" usually refers to an illegal action which is not supported by this community...

Comment: done, but that's a pretty uptight thing to say.

Comment: You still don't really "modify" Unity itself .. you are looking for a configuration. Did you try to set the [Compression](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterOverride.html) to `None`?

Comment: Don't use jpgs? Jpg is an inherently compressed (lossy!) format. If you don't want compression artifacts use png.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you imported your jpg to unity, click on it, and navigate your inspector window to the bottom. You can set the compression property here for every target or to specific build targets.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html

[image]

This way your asset will not be compressed in builds, btw JPG is already compressed.

Comment: OK THANK YOU, yes this was the answer I was looking for.  Thanks.  I know JPG's are lossy but I like the JPG's I prepare from Photoshop and I don't want them doctored any further.

Comment: I see, glad i could help!